# Is it possible to change subpage name to searched word?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to rename a subpage to searched word?

So for example if you search "abc" in the search box (made using the code below)

```
<input name="name" type="search">
<button type="submit">search</button>
```

Then the site would send you to subpage called "abc"

```
https://examplewebsite.com/abc
```

**EDIT:** 
Thanks to Justinas for telling me the answer. To get this working you need to change these 2 lines to

```html
<input type="text" id="name">
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="Search(name)" />
```

and then create a new file <your file>.js, then just add a function

```js
function Search(name) {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    window.location.href = name
}
```

Finally, you have to add a line to your website "head" so it reads the javascript file.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="search.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but not with HTML, but Javascript: `window.location.href = 'https://example.com/' + searchWord`

Comment: I think this question is a bit broad. It's not possible in pure HTML, but whether you need Javascript or a redirect with e.g. htaccess is up to the technologies you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Not using HTML on its own, but like this

```js
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  location=document.getElementById("name").value;
})
```

```html
<form>
<input name="name" id="name" type="search">
<button type="submit">search</button>
</form>
```